# Foreach Dynamic Linq Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Hello I'm using dynamic linq and I have query like this one:

```
var result = DataContext.Table
    .Where("Code == @0", CodeId)
    .Select("new(SGL AS First, DBL AS Second)");
```

How can I loop the result?

I'm using something like this code but it doesn't work:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    total = subtotal + Int32.Parse(item.ToString()) * 2
}
```

It returns the following error:

> The input string does not have the correct format.

Comment: The code you have highlighted is not your issue... I believe the issue is inside your foreach

Comment: How can I extract the First value and Second value inside foreach loop? That's what I want to know

Comment: did you check what does result contain?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. There must be something wrong with the contents of the `foreach` loop. Post that and we can help you, until then I'm flagging this question as off-topic.

Comment: This is my foreach

 `foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    total = subtotal + Int32.Parse(item.ToString()) * 2;                    
                }`

Comment: Put a break-point on the foreach statement and check what type/data result has.  I'm pretty sure it cannot be converted directly to an integer, since you are selecting two columns.  The result is probably an IEnumerable of a dictionary or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `foreach` loop, not with the dynamic linq. This line:

```
total = subtotal + Int32.Parse(item.ToString()) * 2
```

Is going to convert your object to a string, which will look something like this:

```
{First=XXX, Second=YYY}
```

And if you pass that directly to `Int32.Parse` you will get the error you describe.

Instead you want to work on the properties of the object. One way is to cast the object to a `dynamic` value, then you can get the properties as you would any other object:

```
dynamic obj = resultItem;
total = subtotal + Int32.Parse(obj.First) * 2
```

Comment: yes, selected two fields and he is trying to convert them into Int

Comment: Hello I used your code and I got this error: The operator '*' can not be applied to operands of type ' DynamicClass1 ' and ' int ' Thanks for your reply

Comment: @LuisLora What are the types of `total` and `subtotal`?

Comment: @LuisLora Then that error message makes no sense. What code is giving you that error?

Comment: @DavidG the code is working I had another mistake in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should try to

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
  total = subtotal + Int32.Parse(item.First) * 2
}
```

Comment: You can't do this when the type is `object`.